# External data to plot with jQuery Flot

Tags: jquery, json, plot, flot

I am trying to use flot plug-in to plot some data which are wrote into a JSON file. 
It doesn't seem so hard to do but I can't find something that work...can you please help me.

That's the page I've wrote:

```
$(function () {  
    var data;
    $.getJSON("1.json", function(json) {
        var data = json;
    });

    var options = {  
            legend: {  
                show: true,  
                margin: 10,  
                backgroundOpacity: 0.5  
            },  
            points: {  
                show: true,  
                radius: 3  
            },  
            lines: {  
                show: true  
            }
    };

    var plotarea = $("#placeholder");  

    $.plot(plotarea , data, options);  
});
```

while the 1.json file coitain all of the following:

```
{  label: "Values",  
    data:   [   
        [1, 50.026],
        [2, 50.028],
        [3, 50.029],
        [4, 50.026],
        [5, 50.025],
        [6, 50.016]
        ]
}
```

---

@MarcoJohannesen Even if I write "console.log(data)" after the JSON call the script still dowsn't work and no message appear on the screen. Using Chrome utility (I don't remember the name ;-)) I can see that hte file 1.json has been loaded correctly. I think that the problem is that first of all the script is executed and after that the file 1.json is loaded. I've made a little edit on the page.
You can see [a demo on this page](http://bit.ly/sTdXVa)
This is the page "1.htm" code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Graph</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(function () {  
    var data;
    $.getJSON("1.json", function(json) {
        var data = json;
    });
    console.log(data);

    var plotarea = $("#placeholder");  

    $.plot(plotarea , data);  
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the 1.json (I've added the square brackets)

```
[{  label: "Values",  
    data:   [   
        [1, 50.026],
        [2, 50.028],
        [3, 50.029],
        [4, 50.026],
        [5, 50.025],
        [6, 50.016]
        ]
}}
```

---

I definitely found a way to make a working page. That's the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Graph</h1>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("1.json", function(json) {
       //succes - data loaded, now use plot:
       var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
       var data=[json.data];
       $.plot(plotarea , data);  
    });
});

</script>       
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and that's the json file (taken from the flot official exaples to be sure that is correctly formatted)

```
{
    "label": "Europe (EU27)",
    "data": [[1999, 1], [2000, 0.23], [2001, 3], [2002, 4], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]]
}
```

now I'm going to bed but tomorrow I we should try to add the label to the plot and trying with more than one series of values.

Comment: Could you try checking what the $.plot is getting in the data variable?

Comment: @Marco, how can I check this?

Comment: What browser are you using? If you use IE Developer or Firefox Firebug or Chrome Firebug Lite, you can do console.log(data); after the getJSON call :)

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen thanks for the answer. Using Chrome utility I can see that the json file il loaded too late while the plot is already been created. I wrote some details above in the first message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this to generate automatic updated information website for project progress.

My small example using more than one type of diagram: line and bar.

I find it easier to understand if I have a running example, so here we are:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Graph</h1>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("barLine.json", function(json) {
       //succes - data loaded, now use plot:
           var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
           var dataBar=json.dataBar;
            var dataLine=json.dataLine;
            $.plot(plotarea , [
                {
                    data: dataBar,
                    bars: {show: true}
                },
                {
                    data: dataLine,
                    lines: { show: true, steps: false }
                }               
            ]
        );
    });
});

</script>       
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the data(barLine.json):

```
{
"label": "Europe (EU27)",
"dataBar": [[1999, 1], [2000, 0.23], [2001, 3], [2002, 4], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]],
"dataLine": [[1999, 2], [2000, 3.23], [2001, 1], [2002, 5], [2003, 2.3], [2004, 6.5], [2005, 4.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 0.9], [2008, 6.9], [2009, 9.9] ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function () {  
    var data;
    var plotarea = $("#placeholder");

    $.getJSON("1.json", function(json) {
       //succes - data loaded, now use plot:
       $.plot(plotarea , data);  
    });
});
```

And in your JSON file there is a syntax error (starting with  a "[" and ending with a "}".
Could you try this:

```
{  label: "Values",  
    data:   [   
        [1, 50.026],
        [2, 50.028],
        [3, 50.029],
        [4, 50.026],
        [5, 50.025],
        [6, 50.016]
        ]
}
```

Comment: till not working...I've updated the files on-line so you can try if you have a debugger. I've found something which could be interesting but I can completely understand the script http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html and http://burnsforce.com/flot-format-data-flot-readable-json/

Comment: $.plot(plotarea , json);